# dconf refuses to save user profile in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have $XDG_CONFIG_HOME set to ~/.local/etc, but dconf refuses to save its data there, recreating its own ~/.config.
(I have $XDG_CONFIG_HOME set in /etc/profile)

But that's not the only problem.

I tried setting the $DCONF_PROFILE variable to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf, but when using gsettings to change my GTK3 theme I get an error:

```
unable to open named profile (/home/user/.local/etc/dconf): using the null configuration.
The key is not writable
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: in the manpage there's "gsettings needs a D-Bus session bus connection to write changes to the dconf database." which could be related but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

> I have $XDG_CONFIG_HOME set to ~/.local/etc, but dconf refuses to save its data there, recreating its own ~/.config. (I have $XDG_CONFIG_HOME set in /etc/profile)

/etc/profile is read by login shells and by GDM, but dconf is often started outside those contexts – it is likely started through the systemd "user service manager", which doesn't involve a "login-mode" sh/bash and doesn't read /etc/profile.

You'll need to additionally set the environment variable through /etc/environment (see systemd's `man environment.d`).

> I tried setting the $DCONF_PROFILE variable to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf, but when using gsettings to change my GTK3 theme I get an error:

$DCONF_PROFILE points to a *profile file,* not directly to the config storage directory.

As $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf is typically already a directory (the default location for dconf's "user-db" database), it can't be a file at the same time. See `man 7 dconf`.